I am looking for sci-fi story/novel, where some sort birds convinced inhabitants they can see only through their eyes and used this to control them
The story is set on a rather developed planet, where inhabitants can space travel but they are fully controlled by bird-like creatures they have to carry on their head to be able to see. The inhabitants are humanoid but the planet is not Earth.
Later turns out, newborn babies are able to see but lose that ability when a "bird" arrives and sits on their head. From that moment they are blind and must take care of their bird. Birds provide distorted view of the world to achieve their own goals — power.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

So are these controlled inhabitants human/humanoids?

Reminds me of the Mojo birds from Cobra Strike by Timothy Zahn.

yes, controlled inhabitants are humanoids but the planet is not Earth.
